# How to correct Numpy and TPOT array shapes error?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, train-test-split

I'm trying to pass a `feature` and `label` numpy array into `train_test_split`. The features are a single column (datetime dtype converted to integer). There are 900 observations in the `labels` array.

`features.shape` returns `(1101, 1)`

`labels.shape` returns `(1101, 900)`

Before splitting into feature and label arrays I did `df.fillna(0, inplace=True)` because I had thought `NaN` values were the issue originally.

Here is the block I'm running:

```
my_tpot = TPOTRegressor()
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(pd.np.array(features), pd.np.array(labels),train_size=0.75, test_size=0.25)
tpot = TPOTRegressor(generations=5, population_size=20, verbosity=2)
tpot.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

The exceptions occures on the `train_test_split` line. Here is the exception:

`ValueError: Error: Input data is not in a valid format. Please confirm that the input data is scikit-learn compatible. For example, the features must be a 2-D array and target labels must be a 1-D array.`

What is causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out TPOT cannot solve multi label regression problems at this time, that was my problem passing in a a label size of `(101, 900)` isn't going to work. If this is reduced to a single column the code works fine.